# Retrieving generator name in a rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to set up a rails generator, my first one, and for the past two hours I've been stuck on something really simple - How do I get the users inputed name for the generator. This is in an app and not a gem.

So in the case below - How would I get 'Foo' to print on the generator code?

```
rails g block Foo

class BlockGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  puts #Foo (file name)#
end
```

I've tried with both NamedBase and base generators and every method I can find.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

#  EDIT

```
$ rails g block Foo

class BlockGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
  argument :generator_name, type: :string

  puts #Foo (file name)#
end

#result

block
No value provided for required arguments 'generator_name'


$ rails generate block :generator_name => testing

 #result

 is empty, nothing is printed to the console.
```

Comment: You should be able to specify an argument that will map to the users input. You can insert it after the `source_root` line, like so: `argument :generator_name, type: :string`. It would then be available within your generator as `generator_name`. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tinkered with your suggestion for both NamedBase and base, and supplying the argument with a key but each time it only responds with the generator name as the value. In this case 'block'. I've edited the question to demonstrate. Thanks again for the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

name is defined [automatically](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#creating-generators-with-generators) :

> First, notice that we are inheriting from Rails::Generators::NamedBase
>   instead of Rails::Generators::Base. This means that our generator
>   expects at least one argument, which will be the name of the
>   initializer, and will be available in our code in the variable name.

```
class BlockGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  def display_name
    puts name
  end
end
```

Here in action :

```
rails g block Foo
#=> Foo
```

If you need another parameter :

```
class BlockGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  argument :bar, type: :string, default: "Bar"

  def display_name
    puts name
    puts bar
  end
end
```

It outputs :

```
rails g block Foo
#Foo
#Bar

rails g block Foo Baz
#Foo
#Baz
```

Note that if you use the `name` variable inside the class definition but outside of a method, it will be defined, but with `BlockGenerator` :

```
class BlockGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  argument :bar, type: :string, default: "Bar"

  puts name

  def display_name
    puts name
    puts bar
  end
end


rails g block Foo Baz
# BlockGenerator
# Foo
# Baz
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. When I try this however it returns the ClassName. So in this case BlockGenerator

Comment: name variable should be used inside a method. I'll add an example.

Comment: Ahhhhhh- of course, because it fires all the methods. Thank you so much Eric!